# Reverse String in Python with Append

Tags: python

I need to write a string reverse code in python then add A to the reversed string immediately after each occurence of a character. For example the input would be "hello" and the output would be 'oAlAlAeAhA'

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code example that we can help with?

Comment: Please include what you have already tried and where you are stuck exactly. See [ask].

Comment: What have to tried so far? Welcome to stack overflow. Show us some attempt at a solution first and you'll find people being more willing to help.

Answer (score 4):

To make your string a list:

```
text="hello"
text=list(text)
```

This gives

> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

Reverse it using

```
text.reverse()
```

Then join them on an "A"

```
"A".join(text)
```

This gives

> oAlAlAeAh

If you want the "A" at the end too instead use

```
"A".join(text)+"A"
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative in one line:

```
''.join([l + 'A' for l in s[::-1]])
```

which gives:

> 'oAlAlAeAhA'

for `s = 'hello'`

Comment: Also a good answer, but given that this is a fairly beginner question I thought it'd be best to spell everything out and explain all the steps rather than giving them a one-liner they'll just copy without understanding how it works.

Comment: @KJTHoward you are right, I agree, yours is better for a beginner. I just added mine as a further example.